# Неполное придаточное сравнения или сравнительный оборот?

Tags: как, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

*Оба они были красавцы, и оба из сражений выходили целы и невредимы, а дальше шло, **как во всякой доброй сказке**: женились, оправляли свадьбу.*

Во всякой доброй сказке – это сравнительный оборот или неполное придаточное сравнения?

Придаточное сравнения неполное в том случае, если есть члены предложения, относящиеся к группе сказуемого (дополнение или обстоятельство).

Answer (score 2):

*Оба они были красавцы, и оба из сражений выходили целы и невредимы, а дальше шло, **как во всякой доброй сказке**: женились, оправляли свадьбу.*

Это сравнительный оборот. В неполных придаточных предложениях можно обычно восстановить подлежащее или сказуемое по смыслу, например:

(1) Пропущено подлежащее: Мы втроём начали беседовать, как будто (мы) век были знакомы. Лес стоит молча, словно (он) всматривается куда-то своими верхушками и ждёт чего-то.

(2) Пропущено сказуемое: Гостиная набита гостями, как подушка (набита) пером.
Высохшие стулья потрескивали, как дрова (потрескивают) в камине.

Дополнение

**Виктор Астафьев "Звездопад"**

*Вскоре все сказки, какие я знал, кончились, и я стал их придумывать...
Подобных историй, оторванных, как принято сейчас выражаться, от действительности, я наслышался в детдоме от бывших беспризорников. Но я их переделывал на свой лад: Вместо душегуба-блатяги у меня преимущественно действовал благородный воин-храбрец, а вместо купеческой дочери — фронтовая сестра, называемая то принцессой, то царицей. **Оба они были красавцы, и оба из сражений выходили целы и невредимы, а дальше шло, как во всякой доброй сказке: женились, оправляли свадьбу.** Я там был, мед лил и так далее.*

Comment: Интересно, кому не угодил ваш ответ, что поставили минус?

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Наверное, тому, кто дал правильный ответ.

Comment: Ответ поддержал. Хотел бы ещё заметить, что в книгах обычно не ставят запятые в случаях типа: *всё шло как по маслу, всё шло как по нотам, **всё шло как в сказке** и т.п.* Но это больше похоже на устойчивые выражения, чем на сложные сказуемые, наверное.

Answer (score 2):

*а дальше шло* — при изъятии оборота нарушается смысл, значит, оборот должен входить в сказуемое и запятой не должно быть.

**Но!**
Здесь всё решают логические ударения.
Ударение отчётливо падает на слово "шло", и в связи с этим есть запятая. Почему так? Из-за распространения сравнительного оборота.
Сравнить: *а дальше шло как в скАзке; а дальше шло как в доброй скАзке*.

Как это можно объяснить грамматически:
*а дальше шло [**так**], как во всякой доброй сказке...* || Слово "так" там очень подходит, оно подразумевается.

Comment: Оборот не входит в сказуемое, но при тесной связи является обстоятельством, образуя устойчивое сочетание. Однако при распространенности оборота связь ослабевает и он обособляется. Чем длиннее оборот, тем сложнее его прочитать в одну фразу со сказуемым

Comment: Про длину — именно. Обычно входит в сказуемое, если при изъятии нарушается смысл, как указано у Розенталя. Обстоятельство вроде как при фразеологизмах. "Как в сказке" употребляется в прямом смысле, поэтому к ним не относится.

Comment: И эти люди учат кого-то писать грамотно! о-О

Comment: @ЕгорСальков Что не так? У вас где-то средний уровень (не низкий), в продвинутых нюансах (как здесь) вы не разбираетесь.

Comment: @oleedd  Знание ТЕРМИНОЛОГИИ о многом говорит.  Так, СЛОЖНОЕ СКАЗУЕМОЕ по определению совмещает признаки составного глагольного и именного сказуемых, например: хочет стать великим (две связки и именная часть).  Разумеется, здесь ничего этого нет. Поэтому без особой надобности не стоит говорить такие слова, как  «сложное сказуемое».

Comment: А есть у нас УСТОЙЧИВОЕ СОЧЕТАНИЕ на основе глагола и сравнения идиоматического (фразеологического) характера: шло как в сказке, и обособление оборота в этом случае надо рассматривать в условиях контекста http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147
Контекст же позволяет нам определить расстановку логических ударений: при обособлении ударение падает и на глагол, и на оборот, так как сложно прочитать в одну фразу и глагол, и распространенный  оборот.

Comment: @Sharon "Как в сказке", в отличие от "как по маслу", употребляется в прямом значении, поэтому для фразеологизма не подходит (значение не "очень хорошо", а "так, как в сказках"). Но некоторая устойчивость имеется, но это не повод для отсутствия запятой (где в правилах сказано о устойчивых выражениях?). У Розенталя сказано: если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота).

Comment: Можете тогда сказать, когда входит, а когда тесно связан по смыслу? В примере "*Всё как у людей.*" оборот не входит в сказуемое, а является им.

Comment: Все как в сказке. Здесь оборот - это именная часть сказуемого. Все шло как в сказке. Это у вас что? В каких отношениях состоят глагол и фразеологический оборот? У Розенталя какое-то неопределенное сочетание (входит в сказуемое). Как это входит? Лопатин таким выражением уже не пользуется, Да и в грамматике вы его вряд ли найдете. Тесная связь - да, но и это требует расшифровки. –

Comment: Почему часть? Это всё сказуемое. Где вторая часть? Почему фразеологический? Какое тогда у него значение, если не прямое? Можете ответить на все эти вопросы?

Comment: Все БЫЛО как в сказке. Видите вторую часть? Фразеологический - это устойчивый оборот, а не метафора какая. Белый как снег, бояться как огня - это тоже не метафоры, а прямое значение.  Будьте точны в определениях, это никогда не помешает.

Comment: Вы говорили про часть в "*Все как в сказке.*", а уже хитрите. Стоп-стоп, "белый как снег" цельное, а мы только о фразеологическом обороте с КАК. Вспомните определение слова "фразеологизм" (например, *устойчивое словосочетание, значение которого невыводимо из значений составляющих его компонентов*).

Comment: Егор, к вам обращение через @ было всего один раз. Дальше никто к вам не обращался. Наверно, это система за вашу безграмотность так наказывает.

Comment: «Егор, к вам обращение через @ было всего один раз. Дальше никто к вам не обращался» — интересно, другие здешние знатоки «продвинутых нюансов» (о-О) тоже не знают, что 1 + 1 = 2? :))

Answer (score 1):

«Шло как во всякой доброй сказке» — это сложное сказуемое, и запятая здесь не нужна: ни оборота, ни «неполного придаточного сравнения», что бы это выражение для вас ни значило, здесь нет.

Кстати: «как во всякой доброй сказке» — (КАК?)